# The process of Reskining the Apps

Tags: google-apps

Want to reskin some apps and want to know from where I learn this method with working on some projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should first make sure that the app you're working with has a licence permitting you to edit it.
You can then use `apktool` to decompile it's apk and modify its resources.
You should then compile the edited source and sign it before you can install it on your phone.